# How to enable provided scope in subproject{} in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, war

Suppose we have a multi-project build. Eventually the entire project is bundled into a war. We know the web container will provide some utility jars, say, some logging-related jars, so we want to use a `provided` kind of scope. The `war` plugin offers the nice `providedCompile` and `providedRuntime` configuration. However, we want to use the `war` plugin only in the subproject that creates the war. So, the problem is, how can we use something like `providedCompile` and `providedRuntime` in other sub-projects? Ideally, we want to apply that scope to the logging jars in a `subprojects {}` closure.

**update**
My scenario is like below.

In the root `build.gradle`, I have something like this:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'maven'

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'                // already provided by the servlet container
        compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'    // already provided by the servlet container
        runtime 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2'     // already provided by the servlet container
        runtime 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.2'        // already provided by the servlet container
...
```

These dependencies are used not just by the war sub-project, but they should be excluded in the war. Therefore, I need some mechanism to achieve this.

BTW, I have already worked out a solution.

Comment: So You need to *simulate* war provided configurations in other subprojects? Why? What is the scenario? You can also provide an example with desired output described.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to achieve a `provided` scope.

**Option 1**
Create a custom configuration `provided`. For example:

```
configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets.test {
    runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
}
```

The downside of this approach is that IDEs, for instance, IntelliJ IDEA, probably don't understand custom configuration and hence are not able to pull dependencies correctly. This happened to me with IntelliJ IDEA.

**Option 2**
Use the predefined `compile` and `runtime` configurations. Then, in the build.gradle of the war sub-project, filter out the jars of your choice. For example,

```
war {
    Set exclusions = ['slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar', 'javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar',
                      'logback-classic-1.1.2.jar', 'logback-core-1.1.2.jar'] as Set
    classpath = classpath.filter { file ->
        !exclusions.contains( file.name )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [gradle 2.12](https://docs.gradle.org/2.12/release-notes), it is possible to use [`compileOnly`](https://docs.gradle.org/2.12/release-notes#support-for-declaring-compile-time-only-dependencies-with-java-plugin) when using [`java plugin`](https://docs.gradle.org/2.12/userguide/java_plugin.html).

https://docs.gradle.org/2.12/release-notes#support-for-declaring-compile-time-only-dependencies-with-java-plugin